# The requested URL was not found on this server. (Laravel, XAMPP, Windows)

Tags: php, laravel, windows, xampp, frameworks

Just started using Laravel(^9.19), the index page loads without errors, but whenever I click on a link it gives back 404 status code:
"Not Found
The requested URL was not found on this server.
Apache/2.4.53 (Win64) OpenSSL/1.1.1n PHP/8.1.6 Server at localhost Port 80".

I've seen this problem multiple times on stackoverflow, but most of the solutions are for Ubuntu systems, but I tried those things that are the same on Windows.

I've had a clean XAMPP install. Laravel .htacces file is in the public folder and looks like this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Send Requests To Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

The httpd.conf file has "AllowOverride All" everywhere, and the mod_rewrite is enabled.

Furthermore I tried using other ports too, but it doesn't seem to be the problem, and the URL I got back is the right one.

Codewise I did the things from a tutorial and everything checks up except this error.

Comment: Have you tried restarting the Apache service? Also can you verify if your `.htaccess` file is being read? On windows a common issue is not showing file extensions and your file might be named something different like .htaccess.txt. To create an .htaccess file on windows, you need to actually name it `.htaccess.` with an ending . then it will truncate the dot when it saves. Alternatively save through an editor. Try also making the .htaccess file error, to see if you get an internet server error to verify it's being read. Also make sure your site's web root is /public, not the directory under it

Comment: Yes I have restarted it multiple times using "httpd -k restart" in /apache/bin/ and also used "hard reset and delete cache" on the site after every change.
I have showing file extensions set, and even the file type is listed as "HTACCESS File".
Tried the method that you wrote and when the .htaccess has errors, the /public folder doesn't appear in localhost, after I fixed the file the /public folder appeared, so I think it is read. And it has no subfolders.